# scrapy xpath why this page is empty thouh i can see it in chrome f12 tool?

Tags: python, google-chrome, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am web-scraping [this page](https://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/rent/apartment-for-rent-abu-dhabi-al-reem-island-3093563.html) using Scrapy.

When I call this xpath:

```
.//div[@class='readmore-concealed-container']
```

I got empty result though I can see it in the chrome developer tools. Why is that please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the dynamic nature of the site. The HTML that Scrapy gets is not the same as you see in the browser developer tools because there is javascript code being executed by the browser that changes the DOM. You cannot replicate the same behavior in Scrapy, Scrapy is not a browser.

Assuming you want to get the primary phone number, you can extract it from a different location on the page. Demo from the [`scrapy shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
$ scrapy shell https://www.propertyfinder.ae/en/rent/apartment-for-rent-abu-dhabi-al-reem-island-3093563.html
In [1]: response.xpath('//li[@class="phone"]/a/@data-phone').extract()[0]
Out[1]: u'+971 X XXX 21XX'  # added X for privacy reasons
```

Comment: I can't use the css selector, i am just allowed to use xpath.