# Why does xpath half-work in this web page?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

Many elements in this [web page](https://www.mercedes-benz.co.in/passengercars/buy/new-car/search-results.html/?emhsort=price-asc&emhvehicleAssortment=vehicles&emhstockType=IN_STOCK) are unselectable by Xpath

I'm Trying to get the names of the cars, I'm using selenium with Python to get their names. I wait 40 seconds before trying to get their name for it to load.

Theese

```
//h2[@class="wb-vehicle-tile__title"]
```

```
//article[@class="wb-vehicle-tile emh-vehicle-tile"]
```

and many more don't work.

Comment: Have a [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28684950/1305969). The problems probably arise due to the dynamic nature of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the complete solution:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions, Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = "https://www.mercedes-benz.co.in/passengercars/buy/new-car/search-results.html/?emhsort=price-asc&emhvehicleAssortment=vehicles&emhstockType=IN_STOCK"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
# click on the "Agree to all" button to proceed 
shadow_element_1 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "cmm-cookie-banner.hydrated").shadow_root
shadow_element_1.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.button-group').find_element(By.XPATH, 'button[text()="Agree to all"]').click()

# enter the pin code to proceed further
shadow_element_2 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'dh-io-emh-region-picker[class="webcomponent webcomponent-nested"]').shadow_root
region_picker = shadow_element_2.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#postCodeInput')
region_picker.send_keys(110001)
region_picker.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# parse the search results
shadow_element_3 = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'emh-search-result[data-component-name="emh-search-result"]').shadow_root
search_container = shadow_element_3.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.dcp-cars-srp__results.dcp-cars-srp-results.srp-grid-layout__results')
results = search_container.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.dcp-cars-srp-results__tile')

for result in results:
    print(result.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h2.wb-vehicle-tile__title').text)

time.sleep(5)
```

output:

```
GLB200
GLB200
GLB200
C220d MY23
C220d MY23
C220d MY23
C220d MY23
C220d MY23
C220d MY23
C220d MY23
C220d MY23
C220d MY23
```

Things to notice:

1. First of all, we need to find and click on the `Agree to all` button which lies under a `shadow-root`.
2. Next, we need to find and input the pin code (which again lies under a `shadow-root`) to proceed further.
3. Finally, we get to the search page where we can see 12 different search results. We find the element (this element also lies under a `shadow-root`) which contains the search results data.

The variable `results` holds all the 12 results on the page and we can iterate over it to extract/parse all the pieces of information.